# How to shutdown elasticsearch completely?

Tags: elasticsearch

Could anybody help me how to shutdown elasticSearch completely ! It starts automatically when system starts.

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: What OS are you using it on?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Ubuntu 15.04+**

```
systemctl disable elasticsearch
```

For **Ubuntu < 15.04**

To toggle a service from starting or stopping permanently you would need to:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/SERVICE.override
```

where the stanza manual will stop Upstart from automatically loading the service on next boot. Any service with the .override ending will take precedence over the original service file. You will only be able to start the service manually afterwards. If you do not want this then simply delete the .override.

For more details, you may [check this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should because you are initialing it in the `config` file, which fires every time the system starts.

To answer your question, I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191539/how-to-stop-shut-down-an-elasticsearch-node) should help.

Answer (score 0):

It probably runs as a service. If it is on linux remove the service file, usually on `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch`

If it is on windows - there is a service.bat file on the installation/bin folder, you can uninstall using:

```
service.bat remove
```